# CQL: filter row with empty columns

Tags: null, cassandra, cql

I have a cassandra database and a column family with columns (secondary keys) A, B, C. I need to select all rows from it, but filter rows with empty B column. Is it possible to do that using CQL? Or maybe it's possible just to select rows with empty column (in cql, secondary keys may be filtered only by exact value)?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not currently possible.  The filtering has to happen client-side.

If this is a type of query that you know you will need ahead of time, I recommend maintaining an index of the rows with no B column.

Comment: Could you, please, clarify what you mean by "maintaining an index of the rows with no B column"? I am phasing a need equal to that of Yuriy.

Comment: @mico For example, in a separate CF, use one row to store the keys of all rows that have no B column in the first CF.  Each row key would go in a new column.